# Pester Mock a command within a PowerShell class function

Tags: powershell, class, mocking, pester

I've found a lot of questions about mocking a function (method) within a PowerShell class. The question I have (and can't find an answer for) is, is it possible to mock a cmdlet call that is contained within a PowerShell class?

To be clear - this is about testing the function/method in the class, not mocking the function/method from the class for which there are a number of options available.

Example:
PowerShell Class - test.psm1

```
class MyClass {
    [string]$filecontent

    MyClass() {}

    [void] GetFileContent([string]$filepath) {
        $this.filecontent = Get-Content -Path $filepath -raw
    }
}
```

Pester file:

```
using module .\test.psm1

Describe "MyClass" {
    BeforeAll {
        $objClass = [MyClass]::new()
        Mock Get-Content { return "this-is-a-test" }
        $objClass.GetFileContent("c:\temp\myfile.txt")
    }

    It "Should update class variable" {
         $objClass.filecontent | Should -be "test-is-a-test"
    }

    AfterAll {
        Remove-Variable objClass
    }
}
```

I had expected (or rather hoped) to mock the cmdlet Get-Content within the class function/method GetFileContent, but Get-Content is not mocked - and it tries to call the file which may not exist in testing.  Any ideas of how to mock these cmdlets?

Many thanks

Martin

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an alternative to Mocking when dealing with file paths is to use [TestDrive](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/testdrive), assuming for your class you can specify the path to the file via an input parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to make this work is to use the [`-ModuleName` Parameter](https://pester.dev/docs/commands/Mock#-modulename) in your [`Mock`](https://pester.dev/docs/commands/Mock) statement, this is so the cmdlet gets overridden in the Module's scope.

> Optional string specifying the name of the module where this command is to be mocked. This should be a module that *calls* the mocked command; it doesn't necessarily have to be the same module which originally implemented the command.

The argument for `ModuleName` in this case would be `test`, this is determined by your `psm1` file name.

In summary:

```
using module .\test.psm1

Describe 'MyClass' {
    BeforeAll {
        Mock Get-Content -ModuleName test { return 'this-is-a-test' }
        $objClass = [MyClass]::new()
        $objClass.GetFileContent('c:\temp\myfile.txt')
    }

    ....
    ....
}
```

Alternatively, hint provided by [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42), you can use [`InModuleScope`](https://pester.dev/docs/commands/InModuleScope) wrapping `Describe`:

```
using module .\test.psm1

InModuleScope 'test' {
    Describe 'MyClass' {
        BeforeAll {
            Mock Get-Content { return 'this-is-a-test' }
            $objClass = [MyClass]::new()
            $objClass.GetFileContent('c:\temp\myfile.txt')
        }

        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: @zett42 nice one! wasnt aware about that one either